# field may refer to more than one table error... but I only have one table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an Access query with only one thing in the FROM clause, but its throwing error

> The specified field 'HR_UntrainedList.ProgramTitle' could refer to
>   more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.

```
Select HR_UntrainedList.ProgramTitle, 
       Count(HR_UntrainedList.ProgramTitle) as CountOfProgramTitle
FROM HR_UntrainedList
GROUP BY HR_UntrainedList.ProgramTitle;
```

I'm really confused at this error because I only have one table.  Whats happening here?

Comment: Try removing the table name from all the columns.

Comment: @Fireblade -No help, now its asking me for parameter values.

Comment: Is HR_UntrainedList a query or table?

Comment: @DonJewett - Its a query.

Comment: Then I would suggest the error is coming from HR_UntrainedList. That needs to be ruled out first.

Comment: @DonJewett -HR_UntrainedLIst is a SQL pass-through query which runs fine by itself, so I don't think the issue is there.

Comment: The next thing to check would be any RowSource properties set for field lookups in your table.

Comment: @DonJewett -There aren't any, all data comes from SQL server as a passtrhough.

Comment: what happens if you create a brand new query and paste in the SQL exactly as shown in your example?